# How to upload video to Youtube by own website?

Tags: php, mysql

How to upload video to Youtube by own website?

On my website, I used PHP and Mysql to work on.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide considerably more information. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking questions - ensure you provide a clear, concise description of the specific problem, and don't forget to explain [what you have tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/). In general questions on StackOverflow should demonstrate a specific problem with a specific **small** section of code that is reproducible on other systems.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the YouTube Upload Widget](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_upload_widget).